# How can I permanently disable the auto-hide taskbar option?

Tags: windows-7

My laptop constantly reenables the auto-hide taskbar option as part of it's power saving options.  I have searched through these options to disable this but cannot find it.  Is there a registry setting or something which allows me to permanently disable the auto-hide taskbar option?  I never ever want it to hide but I am constantly unchecking it every time my laptop is unplugged from the power adapter.

I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to tweak the registry, just go and change your Advanced Power Settings:

1. Right click battery icon and go to '**Power Options**'.
2. Next to the battery savings plan(which should be checked when your laptop isn't plugged in), go to '**Change Plan Settings**'.
3. When that window pops up click on '**Change Advanced Power Settings**'.
4. Find and expand something similar to '**Power Settings**', then expand something similar to '**Battery Saving Desktop**'.
5. Change the setting to '**Disabled**' for both **Plugged In** and **On Battery**
6. Click Apply and then OK :)

Note that other power plans may have the option set on enabled, so if you change your power plan then you might have to repeat the process again for that particular Power Plan. If you want to disable auto-hiding for ALL power plans, just change the [active] plan to another plan and carry out steps 4,5,6 and do it for other plans etc.

Comment: Hooray!!! You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out!  Thank you so much for saving me from my frustration!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)